# Multiple DropDownList in an IEnumerable Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I'm developing a mini-survey with ASP.NET MVC. I created my models Question, QuestionCategory, Response, ResponseCategory and populated them with seed data.

The Index View of the Question Model is working pretty well but I need to add an extra field which will contain a drop-down list for each questions where users can be able to answer the question with the option selected with the drop down list.

Below is my Question Model

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Survey Question")]
    public string SurveyQuestion { get; set; }
    public QuestionCategory QuestionCategory { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Question Category")]
    public byte QuestionCategoryId { get; set; }             
}
```

And here is my QuestionCategory Model

```
public class QuestionCategory
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string QuestionCat { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Response Model

```
public class Response
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string ResponseName { get; set; }
    public byte Weight { get; set; }
    public ResponseCategory ResponseCategory { get; set; }
    public byte ResponseCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the ResponseCategory Model

```
public class ResponseCategory
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string ResponseCat { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the Index Action of the QuestionController.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var questions = _context.Question.Include(q => q.QuestionCategory).ToList();
        return View(questions);
    }
```

And finally below is the view which displays the questions with the

```
@model IEnumerable<WorkPlaceBullying.Models.Question>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Survey Questions";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Questions</h2>
@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <p>We don't have any Questions yet!.</p>
}

@Html.ActionLink("Question", "New", "Question", "", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Questions</td>
            <td>Response Category</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var question in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@question.Id</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(@question.SurveyQuestion, "Edit", "Question", new { id = @question.Id }, null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @question.QuestionCategory.QuestionCat
            </td>
            <td>               
                @*@Html.DropDownListFor(q => q.Question.QuestionCategoryId, new SelectList(Model.QuestionCategory, "Id", "QuestionCat"), "Select Question Category", new { @class = "form-control" })*@
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I can't seem to fit in the dropdownlist for the responses in the Index view of the Question Controller. All help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SelectList Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist.aspx#Anchor_5) takes an IEnumerable, not a class.

Create a List of Model.QuestionCategory's in your model and create a SelectList from that.

```
public static IEnumerable<QuestionCategory> QuestionCategoryList = new List<QuestionCategory> { 
    new QuestionCategory {
        Id = 1,
        QuestionCat = "Red"
    },
    new QuestionCategory {
        Id = 2,
        QuestionCat = "Blue"
    }
};
```

Change the code in the View to:

```
@Html.Hidden(@question.Id + "_QuestionCategoryId", @question.QuestionCategoryId)
@Html.DropDownList(@question.Id + "_QuestionCategoryId", new SelectList(QuestionCategoryList, "Id", "QuestionCat"), "Select Question Category", new { @class = "form-control", onchange="setQuestionCategoryId(this)" })
```

You will probably need some javascript to update a [hidden input](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-hidden-hiddenfor) when the [OnChange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event fires.

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cep9xbx7/) for how to update QuestionCategoryId value with javascript.

```js
function setQuestionCategoryId(selectObject) 
{   
   $("input#" + selectObject.id).val(selectObject.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="1_QuestionCategoryId" name="1_QuestionCategoryId" value="0" />
            
<select class="form-control" id="1_QuestionCategoryId" name="1_QuestionCategoryId" onchange="setQuestionCategoryId(this)">
    <option>Select Question Category</option> 
    <option value="1">Red</option> 
    <option value="2">Blue</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

syntax of dropdownlistfor:

```
MvcHtmlString Html.DropDownListFor(Expression<Func<dynamic,TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectLestItem> selectList, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes)
```

ex:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentGender, 
                    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))), 
                    "Select Gender")
```

In the above example, the first parameter in DropDownListFor() method is a lambda expression that specifies the model property to be bind with the select element. We have specified StudentGender property of enum type. The second parameter specifies the items to show into dropdown list using SelectList. The third parameter is optionLabel which will be the first item of dropdownlist. So now, it generates  element with id & name set to property name - StudentGener and two list items - Male & Female as shown below.

Source:http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor

Comment: I already know how to use the DropDownListFor Html helper but what I'll like to know is how to use it for a survey where you have question and you have to select answers either in dropdownList or a radio button.